# How do I add a glossary number in the description in latex/overleaf`?

Tags: latex, overleaf, glossary

I am currently writing my report on Overleaf and I have a query regarding the glossary.

here is the definition of the glossary :

```
 \newglossaryentry{vp} {
     name= Verification Plan,
     description={A verification plan is a list of the procedures and methods to be used for verification} }
```

and I reference this glossary in my description as :

```
    The development phase includes \gls{vp}, creating a verification environment, testbench, and test case development.
```

Now my question is, is there a way I can have a numerical-superscript printed in my pdf for the glossary entry(in my case, it is for the word **verification plan**) which indicates the glossary number? So if in my glossary page, there are 10 words with definitions, and if the word **verification plan** is the 7th word, then in my pdf doc I want to have a superscript of '7' for the word **verification plan** as shown below :

[image]

The reason why i want to do this is so that my professor/any reader finds it easy to refer and moreover, by using this subscript, I want to indicate that this word has been defined in the glossary.

Thank you!

edit #1 : **(PLEASE IGNORE THIS EDIT, REFER EDIT #2)**
As requested I have added a minimal reproducible example as follows.

```
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{vp}
{
    name= Verification Plan,
    description={A verification plan is a list of the procedures and methods to be used for verification}
}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\setglossarystyle{altlist}
\printglossary

\textbf{Develop}: The develop phase includes \gls{vp}, creating verification environment, testbench and test case development.

\end{document}
```

Edit #2 : this is the compilable code :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{vp}
{
    name= Verification Plan,
    description={A verification plan is a list of the procedures and methods to be used for verification}
}

\begin{document}

%\glsaddall
\setglossarystyle{altlist}
\printglossary

\textbf{Develop}: The develop phase includes \gls{vp}, creating verification environment, testbench and test case development.


\end{document}
```

*Edit#2 produces :*

[image]

Comment: can you make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, i have, could you refer to edit#1 ?

Comment: Sorry, but this code fragment won't compile. There is no documentclass, it does not have the necessary packages ...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, my bad, am sorry for that, please refer to edit #2, i have compiled it on my end and was able to generate the pdf for that with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
entrycounter=true
]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{vp}
{
    name= Verification Plan,
    description={A verification plan is a list of the procedures and methods to be used for verification}
}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\setglossarystyle{altlist}
\printglossary

------

  \textbf{Develop}: The develop phase includes \gls{vp}\footnotemark[\glsrefentry{vp}], creating verification environment, testbench and test case development.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!!

Comment: @QTip You're welcome!

Comment: hi, so after playing around with the packages, I had a small doubt wrt footnotemark, 

in my preamble, I make use of the \usepackage{hyperref}, upon using this, the footnotemark[\glsentry{vp}]  doesn't work as intened(the solution you have provided), but if i remove this package, then the footnotemark[\glsentry{vp}] works. So is this behavior common? Is there a work around for this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @QTip If you have a new question, please ask a new question