# Why is hyperref package causing an issue with \footnotemark?

Tags: latex, glossary

I had recently posted a question seeking help for linking a glossary in a specific way and it was resolved, thanks to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for helping me out. [url to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70635718/how-do-i-add-a-glossary-number-in-the-description-in-latex-overleaf/70659513?noredirect=1#comment124919532_70659513)

Now, going ahead with the suggestions, I make use of \hyperref package in my project and that is causing an issue with the use of \footnotemark[]. I have attached the screenshots below along with a MWE.

Screenshots :

**With the hyperref package** I get the error :

[image: TheOutput]

[image: The script error]

**Without the hyperref package** I get the output with no errors :

[image]

MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Input encoding (this file): 8 bit unicode. Default by most text editors
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     % Output encoding (pdf file)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Packages used in the example
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Included graphics and some resizable boxes
\usepackage{url}        % nice urls with line breaks
\usepackage{lipsum}     % nonsense text blocks
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym,
entrycounter=true
]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{vp}
{
    name= Verification Plan,
    description={A verification plan is a list of the procedures and methods to be used for verification}
}
\newacronym{ml}{ML}{Machine Learning}

%%UNCOMMENT THIS AND THERE IS AN ERROR WITH GLOSSARY
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{
%    citecolor=black,
%    colorlinks=false, %set true if you want colored links
%    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
%    linkcolor=black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
%}

\begin{document}

%\glsaddall
\setglossarystyle{altlist}
\printglossary
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

------

  \textbf{Develop}: The develop phase includes \gls{vp}\footnotemark[\glsrefentry{vp}], creating verification environment, testbench and test case development. \acrfull{ml}


\end{document}
```

So in short, I want to have my glossary hyperlinked along with referencing it by using \footnotemark[\glsrefentry....].

Any solution/advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `hyperref`, the `\glsrefentry{...}` macro is a link to your list of acronyms, which conflicts with using it as a footnotemark. You can use  e.g. `\textsuperscript{...}` as a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Input encoding (this file): 8 bit unicode. Default by most text editors
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     % Output encoding (pdf file)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Packages used in the example
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Included graphics and some resizable boxes
\usepackage{url}        % nice urls with line breaks
\usepackage{lipsum}     % nonsense text blocks
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym,
entrycounter=true
]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{vp}
{
    name= Verification Plan,
    description={A verification plan is a list of the procedures and methods to be used for verification}
}
\newacronym{ml}{ML}{Machine Learning}

%UNCOMMENT THIS AND THERE IS AN ERROR WITH GLOSSARY
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    citecolor=black,
    colorlinks=false, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\setglossarystyle{altlist}
\printglossary
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

------

  \textbf{Develop}: The develop phase includes \gls{vp}\textsuperscript{\glsrefentry{vp}}, creating verification environment, testbench and test case development. \acrfull{ml}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I tried this out and it solved my error! :)